# Excel vba refreshing links window interrups macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a  macros that opens a file, makes changes and saves it under some other name. It does so many times. The problem is, the file has links to other files, so when my macros opens that file Excel generates a window that asks whether or not those links should be refreshed.

It interrupts macros and requires manual mouse click, which is something I'd really wish to avoid. Is there any way to ensure it wouldn't happen within macros?

I tried

```
 Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
        For Each cn In resultWorkbook.Connections
                cn.Refresh
        Next
```

But it didn't work - the windows keep appearing.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question (possibly in response to my answer below), next time please comment on the answer so I can be aware of changes to the scope of the question. in this case, I'm still not sure what your problem is -- if you have formula links/references to other files, those are not handled by the `Connections.Refresh` method. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @David Zemens, Hello. I tried but it stilled raised some trouble messages, so I've shut it all down with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. But thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @David Zemens, But by what method would I refresh the connections to other files then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the *UpdateLinks* parameter when calling [`Workbooks.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel). The *UpdateLinks* argument (emphasis added):

> Specifies the way external references (links) in the file, such as the
>   reference to a range in the Budget.xls workbook in the following
>   formula `=SUM([Budget.xls]Annual!C10:C25)`, are updated. **If this
>   argument is omitted, the user is prompted to specify how links will be
>   updated**. For more information about the values used by this parameter,
>   see the Remarks section. If Microsoft Excel is opening a file in the
>   WKS, WK1, or WK3 format and the UpdateLinks argument is 0, no charts
>   are created; otherwise Microsoft Excel generates charts from the
>   graphs attached to the file.